# concat dataframes with different index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to add two csv files and convert to csv.

first.csv

```
 index val1 val2 val3
    0      19    29  30
    1      29    54  30
    2      87    98  90
```

second.csv

```
val4 val5 val6
19    29  30
29    54  30
87    98  90
```

When I try to add the two csv side by side, the columns of second csv comes empty upto first csv rows and only concated.
resule comes:

```
index val1 val2 val3   val4 val5 val6
0      19    29  30
1      29    54  30
2      87    98  90

3                       19    29  30
4                       29    54  30
5                       87    98  90
```

Expected result:

```
index val1 val2 val3   val4 val5 val6
0      19    29  30     19    29  30
1      29    54  30     29    54  30
2      87    98  90     87    98  90
```

I have df1 and df2 two dataframes of that csv.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df3.to_csv('test1.csv',',',dtype='unicode8')
```

Why I'm getting this problem. 
Please help on this issue Thanks,
Sundar

Comment: `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` this should work. I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` and go ahead as usual.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]], columns=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
df1


+---+--------+------+------+
|   |   val1 | val2 | val3 |
+---+--------+------+------+
| 0 |      1 |    2 |    3 |
| 1 |      4 |    5 |    6 |
| 2 |      7 |    8 |    9 |
+---+--------+------+------+

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]], columns=['val4', 'val5', 'val6'], index=[2, 9, 8])
df2


+----+------+------+------+
|    | val4 | val5 | val6 |
+----+------+------+------+
| 2 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
| 9 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
| 8 |    7 |    8 |    9 |
+----+------+------+------+

df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).to_csv('saveit.csv')


+---+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   |  val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 |
+---+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 0 |     1 |    2 |    3 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
| 1 |     4 |    5 |    6 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
| 2 |     7 |    8 |    9 |    7 |    8 |    9 |
+---+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Created data frames by doing:

Copied following:

```
val1 val2 val3
19    29  30
29    54  30
87    98  90
df1=pd.read_clipboard();

val4 val5 val6
19    29  30
29    54  30
87    98  90
df2=pd.read_clipboard();
```

Could you please try following.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
  val1  val2 val3  val4  val5  val6
0  19    29   30    19    29    30 
1  29    54   30    29    54    30 
2  87    98   90    87    98    90
```

Comment: OP has already performed that. The problem lies with index. `df2` has different index than `df1`

Comment: @meW, IMHO OP is NOT getting output in correct format, so I had added this solution.

Comment: I agree to your solution. However, OP has applied `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)` as can be seen in question but due to varying index, OP isn't getting the expected answer.

Comment: @meW, sure may be OP is not creating df correctly, so I have edited solution now how I created df correctly and got output correctly.

Comment: @sundarr, you could try to create df correctly without index column and try once that `df(contact` command?